# How to efficiently extract the visible areas of a Bitmap?

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

I have a bitmap and would like to create and use a filter that would take all the visible parts of the bitmap (all pixels with alpha != 0) and set them into a particular value while drawing on an Android view.

I was able to achieve this with a simple for-loop on the bitmap:

```
private int maskAlpha = 0xAA;
private Paint maskPaint;
private Bitmap targetViewLayoutBitmap;

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    maskPaint.setColor(Color.argb(maskAlpha, 0, 0, 0));
}

...

private void setTargetViewLayoutBitmap(final Bitmap viewBmp) {
    for (int x = 0; x < viewBmp.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < viewBmp.getHeight(); y++) {
            int pixel = viewBmp.getPixel(x, y);
            boolean isVisiblePixel = ((pixel & 0xff000000) != 0);
            targetViewLayoutBitmap.setPixel(x, y, isVisiblePixel ? 0x00ffffff : 0xff000000); 
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
    canvas.drawBitmap(targetViewLayoutBitmap, targetViewLeft, targetViewTop, viewMaskPaint);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: one get/setPixels call instead multiple get/setPixel in setTargetViewLayoutBitmap

Comment: @Selvin - I guess that could make things a bit faster (and have a memory cost on the other hand). The answer I am looking for should probably be using a ColorMatrix or maybe a PorterDuffColorFilter as those can use hardware acceleration.

Comment: did you tried ColorMatrix :   `[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 255,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 255,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 255,
     0, 0, 0, 255, 0 ]` ? but it would produce  `isVisiblePixel ? 0x00ffffff : 0xffffffff` ... edit: `[ 0, 0, 0, -256, 255,
     0, 0, 0, -256, 255,
     0, 0, 0, -256, 255,
     0, 0, 0, 255,  0 ]`

Comment: why?  alpha = 0 then you wana 0x00ffffff else 0xff000000 ... for new RGB channels => `clamp(alpha * (-256) + 255)` = {0 for alph > 0; 255 for alpa == 0}, .... for new alpha channel `clamp(alpha * 255 + 0)` = {255 for alpha > 0; 0 for alpha == 0}

Comment: @Selvin, just for understanding, what does -256 mean in the context of the matrix?

Comment: -256  is too defensive ... -255 should be ok ... if alpha is 1 the R' value with this matrix = clamp(-255 * 1 + 255) = clamp(0) = 0, ... if alpha is 255 the  R' value with this matrix = clamp(-255 * 255 + 255) = clamp(-65025) = 0 ... , if  alpha is 0 the R' value with this matrix = clamp(-255 * 0 + 255) = clamp(255) = 255 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I figured out the solution below using a ColorMatrixColorFilter works in an optimal way (applying the matrix takes less than 1/20 of the for-loop).

```
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    viewMaskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    viewMaskPaint.setAlpha(maskAlpha);

    colorFilterMatrixPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    colorFilterMatrixPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[] {
        0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, -255, 255
    }));
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

private void setTargetViewLayoutBitmap(final Bitmap viewBmp) {
    targetViewLayoutBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewBmp.getWidth(), viewBmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetViewLayoutBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(viewBmp, 0, 0, colorFilterMatrixPaint);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
    canvas.drawBitmap(targetViewLayoutBitmap, targetViewLeft, targetViewTop, viewMaskPaint);
}
```

Thank you for @Selvin for pointing me to the right direction (this solution was an interpretation of what you suggested).

Comment: hehe, my suggestion was opposite :) ... instead solution for `isVisiblePixel ? 0x00ffffff : 0xff000000` I gave solution for `isVisiblePixel ? 0xff000000 : 0x00ffffff` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PorterDuffColorFilter` with a `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN`.

This example takes a `Drawable` and changes every non transparent pixel to green:

```
drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
```

Note: You can easily apply it to a `Bitmap` converting it into a `Drawable` using

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), yourBitmap);
```